# Jump from the beginning of a line to the end of the line above

Tags: vim, keyboard, macvim

I want to know what is required in .vimrc to achieve the following.

Consider the following situation:

Line 1 -> ABC DEF GHI

Line 2 -> JKL MNK OPQ

where A and J are both the beginning of each line, and I and Q are the end of those lines, respectively.

Case (1)
Suppose that the cursor is in J. In order to move from J to I, I have to press a key k and a key $ in my current setting. I want to configure MacVim so that pressing a key h brings the cursor to I.

Case (2)
Suppose that the cursor is in I. In order to move from I to J, I have to press a key j and a key 0 in my current setting. I want to configure MacVim so that pressing a key l ("el") brings the cursor to J.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

case(1): `cursor J -> I` :

press `ge` or `gE`

case(2): `cursor I -> J` :

press `w` or `W`

Comment: Though it is not what I was looking for in the first place, I will use it. Thanks (^o^)/

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for

```
:set whichwrap+=h,l
```

(But its help says this setting is not recommended, probably because it's against the original *vi* behavior and might break some macros and plugins.)